# Шаблонизация сайта

Tags: php, javascript, html, css

Подскажите, каким образом можно реализовать шаблонизацию сайта???
В БД есть строки *id : link : page : template* так вот надо что бы в template заносилась запись о шаблоне.

Например:

*id=1 : link=localhost : page=главная : template=mytheme*

*id=2 : link=localhost/about/ : page=О нас : template=mythem2*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот, что использую я:

```
function view($view_name, $data = Array())
   {
       extract($data);
       include(INC.'/view/'.$view_name.'.php');
   }
```

То есть просто для шаблонов использую файлы с нужной разметкой и вставками коротких тегов PHP. Может это и не идеально, но это всё равно легче любых навороченных шаблонизаторов и для меня пока нету никаких минусов. Когда контроллер отработал через модель нужные данные, вызывается функция `view`, с именем представления, и, если надо, параметрами, которые будут вставлены куда надо.

Вот пример простого контроллера:

```
loadModel('profile'); // загружаем модель по работе с данными профиля юзера
$data = Profile::get($_SESSION['id']); // с помощью модели загружаем данные для текущего юзера
view('profile', $data); // загружаем шаблон профиля, передавая ему данные
```

А в шаблоне там уже будут юзаться в нужных местах переданные ему данные. Это самый простой пример.

Comment: А как тогда сделать выбор шаблона для определенной страницы. Например страница главная-шаблон №5, страница контакты-шаблон №6 ???

И не много не понятно куда это все всунуть !

Comment: Ну так это же функция, и в неё передаётся параметр `$view_name` (имя представления), там и пишите. что надо открыть. А пишется этот код в контроллере страницы. Почитайте про **MVC**.  
В-общем: контроллер управляет поведением для этой страницы, к примеру, берёт модель, с её помощью запрашивает данные, возможно, что-то делает вспомогательное, вызывает представление.

Comment: Может я не так понял или не так объяснил. 
Но если коротко то надо такое: 
В БД есть строки id:link:page:template так вот что бы в template заносилась запись о шаблоне. 
Например:
 id=1:link=localhost:page=главная:template=mytheme
 id=2:link=localhost/about/:page=О нас:template=mythem2

Comment: Объяснил в скайпе.

Answer (score 2):

Смотри для начала на Smarty как широкоизветсный шаблонизатор.

Answer (score 1):

Шаблонизация - очень полезная технология, которая позволяет разделять разработку отдельных частей сайта. Так, например, дизайнеры имеют доступ только к CSS/HTML коду, реже JS, при этом они понятия не имеют о том, как работает то, что они модерируют и модифицируют вообще.
С так называемыми "технологами" все обстоит так же: имеют доступ в основном только к реализации функционала - PHP коду, например. Все это вы, конечно же, знали, но это, как вступление что ли =) А теперь к делу.

Реализовать шаблонизацию можно как угодно! Самая простая выгляди примерно так:

```
файл 1 - functional1.php - "половина" сайта вместе со всеми стилями и т.д
файл 2 - functional2.php - вторая "половина" сайта вместе со всеми стилями и т.д
```

**Страница1:**

```
   include("functional1.php");
   echo "Some text";
   // other functional
   include("functional2.php");
```

**Страница2:**

```
   include("functional1.php");
   echo "New text again!";
   // new other functional again!
   include("functional2.php");
```

Как видите, можно реализовать шаблонизацию по-простому: написать некий код, реализующий базовый функионал, стили, прочие штуки и т.д, затем разбить этот файл "пополам", так сказать, при чем разбиение должно происходить в том месте, куда планируется выводить некоторую информацию, реализовывать некий функционал, писать новые стили и т.д. И, наконец, "лепить" каждую новую страницу сайта, как показано выше.

---

Более сложный вид приобретает шаблонизатор, реализуемый в классах. Такие шаблонизаторы гораздо гибче, в некоторой степени даже надежнее, но часто можно обойтись без этого( хоть и не всегда, но довольно часто! ) - хватит и гибкости первого, более легкого.